# Регулярные выражения powershell

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Нубский вопрос, но не могу найти ошибку. Получаю строки в виде:

```
   123   456   789
   1234    56     9
      0     6  1234
```

Необходимо из данной строки вытащить три числа

```
"   123   456   789" -match "(\d+) (\d+) (\d)"*
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Как самый простой вариант у меня получилось вот так (возможно тут будут примеры и лучше):

PS C:\Users> "   123   456   789" -match "(\d+) (\s+) (\d+) (\s+) (\d+)"
True

PS C:\Users> $matches

Name                           Value

----                           -----

5                              789

4

3                              456

2

1                              123

0                              123   456   789